# Express middleware to log errors in Next.js custom server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js, sentry

I don't know how to **log errors** to Sentry correctly using an express middleware, using:

- Next.js v9.0.5
- Express v4.17.1
- Sentry/node v"5.6.2

I tried different middlewares versions with different results. However, not one is the expected behavior.

**Try 1**:

```
function logError(err, req, res, next) {
  Sentry.captureMessage(`${err.stack} - ${err.message}`)
  Sentry.captureException(err)
  console.log('Error reported to sentry.')

  next(err)
}
```

This is not calling the sentry methods and neither is doing the `console.log('Error reported to sentry.')`, is like directly is going to the `next(err)` without executing any code of this middleware.

**Try 2**:

```
function logError(err, req, res) {
  Sentry.captureMessage(`${err.stack} - ${err.message}`)
  Sentry.captureException(err)
  console.log('Error reported to sentry.')

  // Just removing this line from Try 1
  // next(err) 
}
```

Now is executing my code when there is an error! Is logging to Sentry and doing the `console.log('Error reported to sentry.')`! However, when I enter to the page that is failing, the request looks like pending forever without any response. Not what I want...

**Try 3**:

```
function logError(err, req, res) {
  Sentry.captureMessage(`${err.stack} - ${err.message}`)
  Sentry.captureException(err)
  console.log('Error reported to sentry.')

  // Send an error instead of call next(err)
  res.statusCode = 500
  res.send('Internal server error')
}
```

Same result than Try 1 + bonus: `TypeError: res.send is not a function`. What?

**Try 3**:

```
function logError(err, req, res) {
  Sentry.captureMessage(`${err.stack} - ${err.message}`)
  Sentry.captureException(err)
  console.log('Error reported to sentry.')

  // Throw the error instead of call next(err)
  throw new Error(err)
}
```

This is the closest one that I was expecting. Is calling my middleware code reporting the error to Sentry + the request is not pending forever. Nevertheless, the error stack is weird:

`Error: [object Object]
    at logError (/server/logger.js:43:9)`

---

My questions here are:

- How can I do this correctly?
- What is this happening? How does the error middleware work under express / next.js?

Comment: are you using `sentry/node` ? is so you can use default middleware `app.use(Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler());` and `app.use(Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler());` or  in your routes catch the error and  `           Sentry.captureException(e);`